# Error while using linux command in command line terminal

Tags: terminal, command, line

I tired to use the `rm -rf .*` command to delete a hidden file but I am met with these errors:

> rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
>
> rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '..'

Expecting it to remove hidden files.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are two "directories" name "." (actual directory) and ".." (parent directory) in every directory on a linux OS. Both matches your criteria but can not be removed. Thats why you are getting yor messages.
But nevertheless, all files starting with `.` should be deleted